# Sim800L Uploading issues, HTTPACTION returns 0, 302, 701

Tags: arduino-nano, gps, web-server, error

I'm using the Sim800L module and the NEO6M GPS Module in combination with an Arduino nano to create a simple tracking device. I get the data from the GPS and try to upload it to my site with some simple PHP scripts. I'm using this code down here:

```cpp
//the function - which is responsible for sending data to the web server
void sendLocation(String lat, String lon){
 Sim800l.listen();
 //The line below sets the URL we want to connect to
 Sim800l.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\", \"http://" + ipAddress +  "/log_info.php?dev_id=13&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "\"");
 waitUntilResponse("OK");
 //GO
 Sim800l.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
 waitUntilResponse("200");
 Serial.println("Location sent");
 gpsPort.listen();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to use this code, in my serial monitor I get this message:

```cpp
AT+HTTPACTION=0
OK
+HTTPACTION: 0,302,171
error
```

I Looked it up in the datasheet for the Sim800L, and the number 302 means "Found". I'm expecting the number 200 for "OK". I have no idea what I did wrong, the data is not being send to the web server for some reason. I hope you can help. 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
The datasheet with all the errors for the Sim800L
https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/images/2/20/SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09.pdf

Comment: 302 is HTTP code returned by the server. it is used for redirection. try to print the response with HTTPREAD. most common redirection is to https on the same server. does the server support unsecured access with http?

Comment: The server im using does niet support HTTPS. But how would i go about using this command? AT+HTTPREAD=URL or something else?

Comment: page 261 in the manual

Comment: Thanks, im trying it now.

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob with this stuff, I think I've got the syntax wrong but im not getting any response while trying this command

Comment: I figured it out, but HTTPREAD just returns a "1".

Comment: with what parameters did you run HTTPREAD?

Comment: HTTPREAD=0,1 The manual stated the first digit for start byte (witch i assumed would be byte 0?) and the second one for byte length.

Comment: you asked for one character.

Comment: ohhh... That makes sense.. lol. I should just make the last one bigger right? like 1024 or something?

Comment: I used 1024 now, I indeed see it gets redirected, to https://www.t-mobile.nl/prepaid-data-pass Which is weird because i have 4€ of data left...

Comment: redirect to captive portal to enter password before using the network

Comment: Thanks, i am an total idiot. thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

302 is HTTP code returned by the server. It is used for redirection. Print the response with AT+HTTPREAD to see where does it redirectd.